# Can I archive output from ipython's %run (stdout,stderr) and maintain ability to debug interactively?

Tags: ipython

I use `ipython --pdb -c '%run script.py'` from a bash shell to launch
`script.py` in a manner that is very convenient for debugging (the `--pdb`
causes `ipython` to automatically drop into debugger on an exception).

I'd like the `stdout` and `stderr` from `script.py` to be saved to
files in addition to displaying on the screen (like using `tee` and
shell redirections from a bash shell).

I have two requirements that are difficult to satisfy simultaneously:

1. Display and capture `stdout` and `stderr` in a manner that is
      transparent to `script.py`.
2. Preserve the ability to debug after an exception.

I have not found a way to accomplish (1) that does not break the interactive debugger.  I believe this is because `ipython` (or `ipdb`) uses `stdout` to interact with the user during debugging.  If I were willing to modify `script.py` this would not be too difficult (e.g. custom logging logic) but I'm hoping to use this very generically like shell redirection.

Comment: Wrapping the "ipython -c '%run ...'" inside of /usr/bin/script (using the -c argument for the ipython) is the best solution I've found.  However that does not separate stdout from stderr.